# Method visibility for testing partial mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I'm currently writing unit tests to test behavior of a method and would like to partially mock the methods calling injected properties.  For example:

```
public void doSomething() {
  int complicatedInt = 1 + 1;
  if(getProperty().someBooleanReturn()) {
    ... etc. ... 
  }
}
```

So obviously I want to mock the `getProperty()` method in order to expect the `someBooleanReturn()`.  My question is, since I don't want the getter to be visible to other classes, but visible to unit tests, I've currently been making these methods package-private (default scope).  Is there a standard for these types of operations?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks reasonable... and not bad.  There's a standard refactoring in eclipse for making all variable access for the object through the getters / setters. I might go protected in case you ever subclass it and people won't fuss about it being without a modifier.

Comment: Thinking there's reasons for both protected and default, just depending on how you're using the class! Thanks for the comment, rep Wisconsin! =)

Comment: Consider also asking codereview.SE about this with actual (rather than faked) code.  For example [Review of the testing code that I have written using easymock/junit](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27608/review-of-the-testing-code-that-i-have-written-using-easymock-junit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a class and a test class in the same package (possibly in different jars), combined with default visibility, is a standard way to get access to a class internals.